# What causes 'SSL Required' errors from netcraft/survey?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

We have an MVC application that occasionally sends us an error e-mail claiming that someone is trying to access it without using a secure connection.

This is the text of the exception (anonymized):

```
2015-10-04 19:13:19,092 ERROR NightsAndWeekends [(null)] - The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL.

HEAD method on http://oursiteurl.com/

Referrer = http://www.netcraft.com/survey/

IP = 159.203.65.232



System.InvalidOperationException: The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL.
   at System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute.HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at SmartUsageWeb.ActionFilters.ConfigRequireHttpsAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in C:\filepath\ActionFilters\ConfigRequireHttpsAttribute.cs:line 19
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

We have a special ActionFilter to handle the Authorization step, which short circuits it if we don't have a specific key in our web.config (so we can test locally without an SSL cert), but I have confirmed that the security is turned on on the server.

When we visit the indicated url (a regular http:// url), it correctly redirects us to the https:// path, and does not generate an error e-mail.

What can I do to prevent this exception?

Comment: The url indicated is not necessarily the requested resource. Did you attempt to get the requested resource or did you just go to the url specified in the error?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: I clicked the link in the error

Comment: But was that link the source of the actual error? Did you verify which resource was throwing the ssl protection exception? It's possible that you have a protected resource being accessed in an unprotected manner as part of a partial. So the link that is generated in the exception may point to `site.com/SomeController/SomeAction/` when the resource being accessed is actually `site.com/SomeOtherController/SomeOtherAction/SomeResourceId`.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: So far as I have been able to determine, the source is when they hit the index at the home page.  While I anonymized the url in the above post, the url it points at is the base url.  I can't get my system to generate the exception to verify for myself (which is a big part of the confusion).  The site is extremely basic, only using a single layout and a half-dozen images (all contained within the project), so I don't know what resource they could be attempting to access if it isn't a simple view.

Comment: Maybe look at adding a `HandleError` attribute to the action that is getting the error. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx I believe you (and myself,) are getting this because of a spider or other non-normal user access attempt.